# Ruby bundle open, set $EDITOR

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

I am trying to use the command line to open the the jquery-rails gem.  I am using the command: `bundle open jquery-rails` and I am getting the message returned: `To open a bundled gem, set $EDITOR or $BUNDLE_EDITOR`

Forgive me if this is totally newb, but how do I set my text editor Notepad++ like the message is telling me to? I am using windows vista/Rails 3.1

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you mentioned Notepad++ I suppose you are working with Windows. You need to [set an environment variable](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310519) called `EDITOR` containing the path to Notepad++.

Comment: e.g. `setx EDITOR "<path_to>\notepad++.exe" -multiInst -nosession -notabbar` on the command line. (need to change `<path_to>`)

Answer (score 16):

```
vi ~/.bashrc or ~/.zshrc or whatever you have:

export EDITOR=vim
```

Comment: ok, I tried that and variations of that in the command line and IRB with no avail...Am I missing something?  Sorry again, just starting out here.....I am using Notepad++

Answer (score 0):

If you use zsh on Mac OS X,add this line of code into `.zshrc` file:

`export EDITOR="mvim"`

That will make `macvim` to open the gem.

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to reload your bash session after setting `export EDITOR="vim"` in `~/bashrc`